# transfer folder structure from windows?

Tags: ipad, windows, file-sharing

I have some files that are organized in many folders and a given hierarchy (of folders and subfolders) in a windows PC. Now I want to copy them to an ipad.

Is there a way to do that? without having to create new folders in the icloud then copy them from the icloud then remove them.

Comment: If you have less than 5GB of files, your best bet is to open a free Microsoft account then use OneDrive to sync.  It will replicate the *exact* file folder structure on your PC to the cloud and to the iPad (with the OneDrive app, of course).